# How to use Google Talk video chat on Redhat?

Tags: video, redhat-enterprise-linux, chat, google-talk

Is there some way?

[This page](http://www.google.com/talk/otherclients.html) says its not possible 'normally'.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get [Empathy](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy/FAQ#Does_Empathy_support_audio_and_video_chat_with_Google_Talk.3F) running, it should support Google Talk.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with recent versions of [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/) (`Conversation` | `Media` | pick one). Rebuild it from the `pidgin` SRPM if need be.